# How does ASP.NET respond to requests? Can HTML be embedded in C# recursively?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My question came from a simple example in a [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_forms.asp):

```
<html>
 <body> 
 @{
    if (IsPost) { 
        string companyname = Request["companyname"]; 
        string contactname = Request["contactname"]; 
        <p>You entered: <br />
        Company Name: @companyname <br />
        Contact Name: @contactname </p>
    }
    else
    {
        <form method="post" action="">
        Company Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="CompanyName" value="" /><br />
        Contact Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="ContactName" value="" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
        </form>
    }
 } 
 </body> 
</html>
```

1. The C# code embedded blocks (enclosed by `@{}`) in the HTML page in turn have HTML tags (`<form></form>`) embedded in it. Can this embedding way be done recursively or if can unlimitedly?
2. When the browser requesting this page for the first time, the server will compile the `*.cshtml` file and respond to the request with a pure HTML page, with the `else` block used, right?
   Then I input text of **CompanyName/ContactName** from my browser and submit. My logic breaks here:
   How the page is refreshed into the next page? I mean, how the `if` block is executed since I didn't see any code jumping back to that.
   It seems I didn't understand the way the ASP.NET works. Does the submit action trigger the ASP.NET to run the code again?
   I tried to understand it as this:

   1. The ASP.NET as a run-time platform, when get first requested, compile the file and interpret it into a pure HTML page, sending back to the browser to display.
   2. Then I input name and click submit to send it back to the server.
   3. The ASP.NET framework by some (what?) way knows the values belong to specific `*.cshtml` file, or thread being loaded into the ASP.NET process, and know which variables should take the submitted values.
   4. Then the new page is re-built/re-evaluated and sent back to refresh the client's browser display.

Is that the real case?
I didn't aware why **CompanyName/ContactName** values go to **@companyname/@contactname**, since no explicit assignment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@1) Yes, the "mixing" of HTML and C# code can be done recursive. Most HTML tags are detected by by the Razor parse so it switches to "HTML mode" and with `@` you can switch back to "code mode". If HTML is not detected you can use the `<text>my not detected HTML</text>` tag.

@2.1) The Razor code is not compiled to a static HTML file, but to a class which has the same logic in it as the razor file describes and is then compiled and executed on every request.
E.g the following Razor:

```
<p>
    @if (CONDITION) { <span>TRUE</span> }
    @else { <span>FALSE</span> }
</p>
```

is compiled to a "view class" with a render method like the following:

```
public virtual string Render()
{
    response.Write("<p>");
    if (CONDITION)
        response.Write("<span>TRUE</span>");
    else
        response.Write("<span>FALSE</span>");
    response.Write("</p>");
}
```

This compiled class is then kept "in-memory" and so any further request can "re-use it". That is also noticable by the slow first request to a page, where the Razor is parsed and compiled and then the fast "re-requests" where only the render method is executed again.

@2.3) The post-back from your client is routed to your page again, as an empty `action=""` attribute will do that. As you do not use any model-binding no post variables are assigned by default that happens at the following lines:

```
if (IsPost) { // this is true since you made a POST request
    string companyname = Request["companyname"]; // Request contains all values
    string contactname = Request["contactname"]; // submitted in the POST
```

The name of the key inside `Request` is the `name="CompanyName"` attribute of the `input tag`.

Comment: Thanks you. I got question 1. For question 2, do you mean the code is compiled once and stay in server's process forever? And the submit button, though didn't request anything explicitly, will actually act as a request and make the server respond again? How the @companyname is assigned a correct value? I didn't see a explicit assignment. Thank!

Comment: @user3847651: I updated my answer. If there is still something not clear please tell us.

Comment: OK. I noticed "contactname" and "CompanyName" not case-sensitively same, doesn't that matter?